# socket.io import found in one file but not the other? Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am currently trying to set up socket.io to send data between different html files in my application that is running on nodejs.

I have referenced the wrapper script using unpkg as the following:

`<script src="https://www.unpkg.com/browse/socket.io@4.7.2/wrapper.mjs"></script>`

Now in my `server.js` file I import socket.io like this `import io from 'socket.io';` and seemingly, this works just find. The server.js file can find all references when I run it and my server starts. It looks like the following:

```
const io_ = io(http_);
// http_ is the server

// Bunch of other code here

// setting up connection and everything
io_.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Client Connected');

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('Client Disconnected');
  })

  socket.on('editor', (editor) => {
    if(!editor){
      io_.sockets.emit('send editor', editor);
    }
  })
  
});
```

If I understand the example on the socket.io website correctly, I now need to create a socket in my frontend js file using io() and then emit an event. This looks like the following in my code:

```
const socket = io();
if(editor){
  socket.emit('editor', editor);
}

//editor is the data I am trying to send
```

However, this throws an "Uncaught reference Error io ist not defined" error.
Shouldn't the js file be able to find the io() function? The only thing I can think of, is that I need to reference a different file other than the wrapper.mjs. The socket.io website references socket.io.js so I tried adding that script as a reference using
`https://www.unpkg.com/browse/socket.io@4.7.2/client-dist/socket.io.js` but it still can't find io()...

This is my first time working with socket.io and to be honest I find their documentation and examples more confusing than helping in trying to figure out what the issue here is.